# Issue while watching video with windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, video, window

I have recently installed Windows 10 Pro for my laptop. However, there is one problem while watching a video. 
Some videos the picture is not displayed properly as in the picture below.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JctJjIU9rgk
[image]

Also with is what happened when I switching from Superuser tab to the YouTube video tab:
[image]

This problem only happen for some videos not all. 
For example, if I open [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BonXZAulmmM) it is totally okay at that time.

Hope anyone could figure out the problem.

Also this happens only with Google chrome (Version 68.0.3440.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

Comment: how about reinstall the chrome? Or if there is any update or hotfix available?

Comment: I reinstalled about 10 times and the problems still remain. There is no probplem with older version of chrome.

Comment: Do you have this problem on all quality settings of your first link including the best (720p) and the worst (144p) ? (Return the setting to the highest or auto after testing.)

Comment: Update your chrome.  Tested on `Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and it works correctly.

Comment: @tukan: I updated last night but no success. It happened only with newer version. I tried old version and it is okay but then it automatically updates to new version and the problem happens. I tried to install older version many time but no success and now it doesn't allow me to install older version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youtube videos may be differently encoded for different qualities,
so it would be interesting to know if the problem occurs, for example,
on the best quality (720p) as well as on the worst (144p).
(Return the setting to the highest or auto after testing.)

I have downloaded both videos linked in your post and have compared their attributes.
Both are encoded in MPEG-4 with the same resolution of 1280x720
(since I used the 720p setting).

The main difference is that the problematic video is encoded with a higher
bit-rate of 1268 kb/s, while the other one is of lower bit-rate of 707 kb/s.
Confusedly, this is inverted in frame rate : 25 FPS versus 30.

My guess is therefore that Chrome on your computer has for some reason
a problem with a too-high bit-rate.

You should first check if hardware acceleration is enabled in Chrome,
as this passes most of the graphical tasks to the GPU.
Try to toggle it on or off to see if that makes a difference.
See the article :
[How to Turn Hardware Acceleration On and Off in Chrome](https://www.lifewire.com/hardware-acceleration-in-chrome-4125122).

If that does not help, check if Chrome uses the CPU while playing the video.
Using much above the 1-2% of CPU would indicate that it fails on your computer
to use the GPU for this video and falls back to the CPU, which is slower and may cause
problems.

Comment: I will check your solution tonight. It happened for almost 2/3 of videos not only from YouTube but Facebook as well. Last night, I reinstall and update the lastest version but it happened again. I also tried to turn off gpu by --disable-gpu but no success last night.

Comment: Another try would be to install a good codec pack such as [K-Lite Codec Pack](https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm). Might be worth trying, even though Chrome has many codecs built-in.

Comment: I hope it would solve the problem. I tried a lot last night but couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: I thought last night I used --disable-gpu by command line but it didn't do it. I just tried to disable from chrome setting and it works!

Answer (score 1):

That would be frustrating! My first and only guess is that it is a GPU problem with your OS. Is this an older computer? You might want to try updated (or different) graphics drivers. Maybe disable/enable hardware acceleration: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/hardware-acceleration-windows-7.

Comment: Yes, it is Dell Inspiron 14R N4010. This problem only happens with latest version of Chrome and it's happended since I installed windows 10.

Comment: https://www.technize.net/google-chrome-disable-hardware-acceleration/ Maybe try disabling hardware accelleration in chrome

Comment: I notice that the other answer discusses turning off hardware acceleration,  sorry if you already tried it! I would try reinstalling your gpu drivers

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with your graphics driver. Go to Chrome settings and try disabling the option "Use hardware acceleration when available"

You can easily find it by launching this URL in chrome:
[chrome://settings/?search=hardware](http://chrome://settings/?search=hardware)

Comment: This was already proposed and accepted. I suggest reading existing answers before hopping in, and especially the accepted one.